# Mac Not Able to Read SD Card

Tags: macos, formatting, sd-card

I have a microSD that I use in my raspberry pi. I have it plugged into my mac through an adapter and am trying to use it. However I cannot erase any of its contents and it (contents) does not show up on the computer.

The only place I can find it is in disk utility. I am able to erase it and perform first aid but I can only see it show up in Disk Utility, not in finder.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible issues:

1. How is the SD card formatted?  Large (>32 GB) cards might be initially formatted exFAT. You might need to reformat as FAT32 so that it can be read by both devices.
2. The Raspberry Pi might not be updating the file system correctly... if it caches writes, the Pi might need to be shut down after changes for updates to persist.
3. The card reader may not be able to write to the card; try another reader.